# Large, regular product import for Commerce

Tags: commerce, feeds, migrations

I am in the process of developing a new site using Commerce Kickstart.

The site needs to import a fairly large amount of data from a CSV on a regular basis - perhaps 50,000 to 100,000 products at a time, at least every week. (And maybe more often than that.)

I have tried to use Feeds to do a test import of around 30,000 products. (So this creates 30,000 product variations and 30,000 display nodes.) This has proved to be far too slow for my purposes, taking around 18 hours.

So I see my options as follows:

1. Run some profiling to attempt to see why the import is slowing down
   so much (It starts off at around 200 products / minute and slows
   down to 10-20 by the end of the import run.)
2. Following the [strategy here](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/import-hundreds-thousands-records-15-seconds-custom-entities), import into a single table, and use entities to do what I need to do. With this approach, I am concerned about losing or having to re-implement the functionality I need to make the site work - namely faceted search / unknown regular commerce functionality. Each product - each line of the CSV - has numerous fields of data that would have to be stored, so I'm not even sure if this approach would work.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to progress? Or any hints about the above? Or strategies to import the data that I might not have considered?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:-
Looking at the Feeds log, it looks like the product variations imported in 1 hour 20 mins, whereas the product display nodes took 17 hours to create.

Comment: With modules like Elysia Cron you could set the job of rules to be executed every X minutes, or hour, etc, so it could be faster. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used Drush to to execute the Feeds import via Elysia Cron.

Comment: The slowness is probably coming from somewhere inside node_save(), I would suggest profiling it and finding out what's going on.

The single table strategy won't work with Commerce and makes very little sense there (by bypassing the storage you will also bypass the entire commerce api)

Comment: Thank you, Bojan. I *might* be able to use a single table solution - there are around 70 base products that remain the same and can be customised by the 30,000 imported products. (So buy one of 70 items, add a reference to one of the 30,000.) My concern would be that I still need faceted search on there too. At the moment, I'm treating the 30,000 as individual products, with the "base" product as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else.

I used [XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof) in an attempt to figure out why the Feeds import was slowing down so much. It appears that the culprit is [DrupalDefaultEntityController::cacheGet](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3a%3acacheGet/7).

As the number of entries in DrupalDefaultEntityController's entityCache increases, performance drops off a cliff.

I resolved the issue by importing the nodes manually.